Can we access look up tables inside Anchor Program?
I would like to store a few thousands of addresses in a look up table account. In my program I would like to verify that a hardcoded address (or any else) indeed belongs to the list of accounts in the look up table. Is this possible? In image the steps would be to get the account info and deserialize it ?

This is indeed possible, all you have to do is pass in the account and deserialize it and loop the list, or just calc the index off chain and pass it in as a parameter to save on cu costs.
If you face stack violation errors try to zerocopy the account.
Note: solana address lookup program is just another program, it exist as a crate which you can add to your workspace and use its deserialization methods.
